# How to scroll web page till that web element appear and perform required actions

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have scenario if we search for any input we will get multiple table data .
we have "show as text link" present in different table row we need click.

i have written a code it is working fine in IE in one machine same script is not working in different machine due to vary of monitor size!

```
       String rawTextXpath = "//table[@id='view518-table']/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/div[1]/a[text()='Show as raw text']";
            boolean exists = false;
            exists = driver.findElements(By.xpath(rawTextXpath)).size() != 0;

            if (exists == false) {
                system.out.println("No Results found!");
            }
            int i = 1;
            while (exists == true) { 
                try {

                    driver.findElement(By.xpath(rawTextXpath)).click();
                    Thread.sleep(3000);



                }       

                catch (Exception e) {

                }   

                String expandXpath = "//table[@id='view518-table']/tbody/tr[" + i + "]/td[1]/a";
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(expandXpath)).click();

                JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
                jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,150)", "");



                rawTextXpath = "//table[@id='view518-table']/tbody/tr[" + (i + 1)
                        + "]/td[4]/div[1]/a[text()='Show as raw text']";

                exists = driver.findElements(By.xpath(rawTextXpath)).size() != 0;

                i++; 

            }
```

Note : in above script i am scrolling webpage by 150 it will working fine in IE same version in one machine and it is not working same browser in another browsers

Action is 
1. click on show as text link in each table row and then click on expand icon

Above code is not working properly in different system in same IE11 browser because monitor size is different!

Comment: what error your are getting?

Comment: it is able to click on initial 2 links of different table rows but instead of 3rd link it is clicking on somewhere else in a page

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("id_of_element"));

((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);

Thread.sleep(500);
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to subtract the window's height, check the [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) jquery library to call another function on scroll down.

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height()-$(window).height() });
```